# doubts with queries

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a doubt about queries with LINQ library in C#.

I want to order by age, location and hobbies people that works in a company, and they've made calls. I have a class for those persons, and another class for the telephones, but they have no relation, I cannot go from one to another directly.

I've made a query to print all the calls that they've made;

```
private Model model = new Model();
```

( . . . )

```
ShowConsole(this.model.Calls
        .Where(call => this.model.Worker.Any(
                     worker => worker.TelephoneNumber.Equals(call.SourceNumber)))
        .Select(phonecall => new {
            Name = this.model.Employees.First(
            worker => worker.TelephoneNumber.Equals(phonecall.SourceNumber)),
            Duration = phonecall.Minutes
        }));
```

Now, I doubt how to add a condition with .Where, or another method, to check conditions (like, just print those persons which are from Japan).

How can I relate, and add filters and such to a query which plays with classes that are not related with each other directly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `OrderBy` the `Where` and `Select` calls, then use `ThenBy`. If applicable use `OrderbyDescending` and `ThenByDescending`.

Just remember that using multiple `OrderBy` / `OrderByDescending` calls will result in multiple collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Join` (eq SQL INNER JOIN) and `GroupJoin` (for other join kind) LINQ operators.